# Ignore empty lines in perl?

Tags: xcode, perl, automator

I'm trying to write an Automator shell script for Xcode to make my import lists unique. The trick is, I DON'T want them sorted. So I found this perl magic that works almost perfectly:

```
# Print all unique lines
perl -ne 'print unless $a{$_}++'
```

The only rub is that it removes all the empty spaces between my #imports. I like to group imports by their function...

```
//Model  
#import This.h
#import That.h

// ViewControllers
#import ThisView.h
#import ThatView.h
```

...so I'd like to keep the spaces.

is there some variation on the above incantation that will ignore spaces? If not is there another way to affect this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```
perl -ne 'print unless /\S/ && $a{$_}++'
```

"Print unless the line contains a non-whitespace character and already exists in your hash"

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to affect the imports, perhaps the easiest solution is to restrict your deduping to lines that begin with `#`.

```
perl -ne 'print unless /^\s*#/ && $a{$_}++'
```